# Duplicate circle?

Tags: support, duplicates, review, vote-to-close

I was just casting a duplicate close vote on this [question](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/488479) when I got this notice:

[image]

What does it mean and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the question you were trying to close it against was already closed as a duplicate *of this question*. Hence a circle ;)

Please don't close questions against questions already closed as a duplicate. Follow the chain to the origin!