# "Follow the chain to the origin"- Is it ok to follow it always while closing Q as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I have copied "Follow the chain to the origin" from [@seth answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14659/439451)

Today I have seen a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697042/administartor-password-cant-change) and it is a dup.

I have closed it against a [post 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error) which is also a duplicate of another [post 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us)

Here, If you observe, the post 1 answer has 100 upvotes, even it is dup.

It means that one is the better question as more people find it . If I follow chain, I have to close against post 2, then OP will miss post 1. (Here need to observe, the gap between post 1 & 2 is very few months).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those 2 topics are different issues and probably need to be open BOTH.

[Authentication token manipulation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error)

is about recovery mode so "mount the partition rw" is a correct answer (and the only correct one).

[Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us)

is not about recovery mode but about a corrupted shadow file.

Same problem yes, but different circumstances so I deem it valid to have them BOTH open. I casted a re-open vote on the 1st one.

[Administartor password can't change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697042/administartor-password-cant-change)

though needs to be closed against the FIRST topic (the one you used). The other can be helpful but is not about "recovery". I'd leave that as it is though.

Comment: Voting to reopen [post1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91188/authentication-token-manipulation-error) =)

Comment: I agree, keep them both  open