# We have a dupe of a dupe

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Title says it all.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted) is marked as a dupe of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition), which is marked as a dupe of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) :P

Comment: Why is that? Weird...

Comment: Directed at 3k+ users.

Comment: This is not very rare, see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14706/is-it-ok-to-mark-a-question-a-duplicate-of-a-duplicate/14708#14708 and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14658/duplicate-circle/14659#14659

Comment: This is not very uncommon.  It happens quite often, actually

Comment: The issue is that this is an observation. Not sure what to do with it? What do you expect from us?

Answer (score 5):

Unsurprisingly, the first isn't a duplicated of the last question in the chain. "How to resize the filesystem with gparted **while is mounted**" is a different question of "how to resize a partition". [I've voted to reopen the gparted one,](https://askubuntu.com/q/51272/169736) I invite others to do so too.

Now, you've noticed something that I call the "lazy duplicate". Because A and B share 1 possible answer, doesn't mean that A and B are duplicates. Related, maybe, but not duplicates. Duplicates where meant for questions that in essence ask the same thing but use different words. The first was having problems because when he was trying to use gparted to resize the filesystem, it refused to do so. The later has no idea where to start.

BTW, some downvotes are needed on the answers to the gparted question. They are not only wrong but misleadingly wrong.